# How to increase grammars in the Language change model to more than two in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am interested in extending the Language Change model to include more grammars (states) to more than two. How can I do it? I am new to netlogo. I m interested in the areas which I have to focus on( or codes to adjust) in order to include more states instead of states 0 and 1

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I assume you mean the Language Change model in the Models Library. Apart from the obvious changes of numbering states (so that it is 0, 1, 2... instead of just 0, 1), you need to think about what sort of rules you want for updating. That is, how does each agent decide whether to change languages and to which language (such as changing because it doesn't have enough neighbours with its own language, and then chooses the most common neighbour language?)

Comment: It helps a lot. thanks. I will look into that.